# View connection info from Webforms to SMTP

Tags: webforms, emails

I have a Drupal 8 site with webforms and the site is configured to use our Office 365 for mail.

The site's SMTP settings are right because I have been getting auto-generated emails about out-of-date modules.

The webform fails to send, with the meat of the error message:

```
SMTP Error: data not accepted.SMTP server error: DATA END command failed Detail: TenantAttribution; Relay Access Denied [ValidationStatus of '' is EmptyCertificate]
```

What I would like to do is see everything that the webform is using to connect to the SMTP server and what it is sending.  This so that I can make sure the rights settings are being sent.

I would think that it would use the site-wide SMTP settings but as one works (and the test email works too) but the other doesn't, that it is the other (the webform) that has an issue.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @cilefen, I am looking for a method to view the data the webform is using to connect to the SMTP server to see if there is something misconfigured or missing since the site's information for SMTP seems to work and just this one webform does not.  It can be fairly raw, but I am not very involved with custom coding in Drupal (but I do know some PHP coding) and don't expect there to be a "debug" like module that fits this bill.

Comment: Are you using a contributed module for SMTP? If so, which one?